# How do i sum two lists in this case?

Tags: python, list

```
from random import randrange

n = int(input("Enter the number of throws: "))

throw1 = []
throw2 = []


for i in range(n):
    throw1.append(int(randrange(1,7)))
    throw2.append(int(randrange(1, 7)))

final_throw = sum(throw1, throw2)

print(throw1,throw2)
```

I want to sum throw1 and throw2 together but I don't know how(this is not working).

My issue is quite easy to solve but as a beginner I dont see the solution. Please can you help me ?

Comment: Lists can be easily concatenated. In your case the solution is as simple as ``final_throw = sum(throw1+throw2)``

Comment: Do you want a unique number or a list of sum of pairwise element?

Comment: This is the assignment: Record the totals of the two dice rolls in the list and print the list. Choose the number of throws when calling the function

Comment: @Everythingcoolsucks So it's a sum of pairwise and number of throw is a function's argument.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a global sum, you can concatenate lists

```
>>> sum(throw1 + throw2)
38
```

If you want to sum pairwise element, use a comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(throw1, throw2)]
[6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 9]
```

Input:

```
>>> throw1
[2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6]

>>> throw2
[4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case , you can use final_throw = sum(throw1 + throw2)...
It will add throw2 after throw1 in a random order .
The output will be
Enter the number of throws: 3
[2, 1, 1] [5, 6, 3]

Here numbers in list are random.

Comment: The order of `throw1 + throw2` is not random. It preserves the ordering of both lists and puts the second's elements after the first's.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the below approach.

```
import os

throw1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
throw2 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
lists = zip(list1, list2) 
final_throw = [x + y for (x, y) in lists]
print(final_throw)
```